# Find values in a Pandas dataframe and insert the data in a column of another Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I need to convert the Custom Field column rows to columns in a second dataframe. This part I have managed to do and it works fine.

The problem is that I need to add the corresponding values from the id column to the respective columns of the second dataframe.

Here is an example:

This is first dataframe:

[image]

This is the second dataframe, with the columns already converted.

[image]

But I would like to add the values corresponding to the id column of the first dataframe to the second dataframe:

[image]

Attached is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {
"Custom Field": ["CF1", "CF2", "CF3"],
"id": [50, 40, 45],
"Name": ["Wilson", "Junior", "Otavio"]
}

### create the dataframe ###
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


### add new columns from a list ###
columns_list  = []
for x in df['Custom Field']:
### create multiple columns with x ##
  columns_list.append(x)  
### convert list to new columns ###
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=columns_list)
df2["Name"] = df["Name"]
print(df2)

### If Name df3 is equal to Name df and equal to Custom Field of df, then get the id of df   and insert the value into the corresponding column in df3. ###
#### First unsuccessful attempt ###
df2_columns_names = list(df2.columns.values)
for df2_name in df2['Name']:
  for df2_cf in df2_columns_names:
    for df_name in df['Name']:
      for df_cf in df['Custom Field']:
        for df_id in df['id']:
          if df2_name == df_name and df2_cf == df_cf:
            df2.loc[df2_name, df2_cf] = df_id
 print(df2)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Name'], columns=['Custom Field'])
```

As a general rule of thumb, if you are doing for loops and changing *cells* manually, you're using pandas wrong. Explore the methods of the framework in the docs, it can be very powerful :)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much! 

I will follow your advice!